# Should [umn-mapserver] and [mapserver] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags

Most (UMN) Mapserver questions are currently tagged [mapserver]. Should we specify the two tags to be synonyms?

If not, should we re-tag all (UMN) Mapserver specific questions to [umn-mapserver]?

Comment: Mapserver is somewhat generic.  Esri uses it in their url and html page for their REST mapservice.  See this [example](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer).

Answer (score 6):

I'd be against renaming to umn-mapserver - I've not heard it referred to as UMN MapServer in years. Whilst the homepage http://mapserver.org/ notes that:

> Originally developed in the mid-1990’s
>   at the University of Minnesota

It is no longer developed or owned by UMN as far as I can tell, and is not called UMN MapServer in any of the documentation.

It's a shame capitals aren't allowed in tags in this case as we could distinguish MapServer from map-server.

From the stats there are 49 questions tagged mapserver (the majority I believe are related to the software MapServer), and only 3 tagged umn-mapserver. So I'd be for merging these 3 questions to the mapserver tag.